# Typescript - How to sort one object array based on another array with sorted object's fields?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

Typescript - How to sort one object array based on another array with sorted object's fields?

For example:

Array A not sorted

Array B with object's field sorted

Tries to sort Array A based on Array B's order.

```
const unsortedArray = [
{
    repId: "4",
    symbol: "MSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00004"
},
{
    repId: "2",
    symbol: "TSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00003"
},
{
    repId: "55",
    symbol: "APPL",
    orderNo: "20180518-00001"
},
{
    repId: "22",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-0002"
}]

const sortedArrayField = [
    "20180518-00001", 
    "20180518-00002", 
    "20180518-00003", 
    "20180518-00004"
]

// This is the sorted order that I want
const sortedArray = [
{
    repId: "55",
    symbol: "APPL",
    orderNo: "20180518-00001"
},
{
    repId: "22",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-00002"
},
{
    repId: "2",
    symbol: "TSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00003"
},
{
    repId: "4",
    symbol: "MSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00004"
}]
```

The sorted field array can be anything, not just order number, could be symbol, status, etc... Any suggestion???

Looked up some example and tried a few approach, but no elegant solution so far with typescript. No external library plz.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "sorted field". Do you know when you're given the list which property they map to? Could keys in the same list map to different properties? Can a key match multiple objects?  What's the exact criteria for matching a key against an object? It's not clear with your single input example.

Comment: Also, maybe post what you already have, since "elegant" is pretty subjective (and likely to be closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array by using the index of the orderNo in the sorted array:

```js
const unsortedArray = [
{
    repId: "4",
    symbol: "MSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00004"
},
{
    repId: "2",
    symbol: "TSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00003"
},
{
    repId: "55",
    symbol: "APPL",
    orderNo: "20180518-00001"
},
{
    repId: "22",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-00002"
}]

const sortedArrayField = [
    "20180518-00001", 
    "20180518-00002", 
    "20180518-00003", 
    "20180518-00004"
];


// Sort the array by index of orderNo in the sortedArray
unsortedArray.sort((x, y) => 
  sortedArrayField.indexOf(x.orderNo) - sortedArrayField.indexOf(y.orderNo)
);


console.log(unsortedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the field you need to sort based on it so @yadejo solution is right.

If you don't, try the following solution

```
    const unsortedArray = [
  {
    repId: '4',
    symbol: 'MSLA',
    orderNo: '20180518-00004'
  },
  {
    repId: '2',
    symbol: 'TSLA',
    orderNo: '20180518-00003'
  },
  {
    repId: '55',
    symbol: 'APPL',
    orderNo: '20180518-00001'
  },
  {
    repId: '22',
    symbol: 'FB',
    orderNo: '20180518-00002'
  }];

const sortedArrayField = [
  '20180518-00001',
  '20180518-00002',
  '20180518-00003',
  '20180518-00004'
];

const sortedArrayOfObject = [];

for (const sortedItem of sortedArrayField) {
  sortedArrayOfObject.push(unsortedArray.find(item => {
    for (const prop in item) {
      if (item[prop] === sortedItem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }));
}

console.log(sortedArrayOfObject);
```

Comment: This gets tricky when multiple key's in the objects have the same value. But in that case, there really is no way to sort the items :)

Comment: Yes i guess you are right, in that case he should know what is the property he will sort based on it. Nice catch :).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```js
const unsortedArray = [
{
    repId: "4",
    symbol: "MSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00004"
},
{
    repId: "2",
    symbol: "TSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00003"
},
{
    repId: "55",
    symbol: "APPL",
    orderNo: "20180518-00001"
},
{
    repId: "22",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-00002"
}];

const sortedArrayField = [
    "20180518-00001", 
    "20180518-00002", 
    "20180518-00003", 
    "20180518-00004"
];
unsortedArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
  if(sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj1.orderNo) != -1  && sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj2.orderNo) != -1){
  return sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj1.orderNo)- sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj2.orderNo);
} else if(sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj1.orderNo) != -1  && sortedArrayField.indexOf(obj2.orderNo) == -1){
  return 0;
} else {
   return 1;
}
});
console.log(unsortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: `sortedArrayField.map(orderNo => unsortedArray.find(item => item.orderNo === orderNo))`

You can also use this if you have more than one object in the same position:

```
var sortedArray2 = [];
sortedArrayField.forEach(orderNo => {
  sortedArray2 = sortedArray2.concat(unsortedArray.filter(item => item.orderNo === orderNo));
});
```

```js
const unsortedArray = [
{
    repId: "4",
    symbol: "MSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00004"
},
{
    repId: "2",
    symbol: "TSLA",
    orderNo: "20180518-00003"
},
{
    repId: "55",
    symbol: "APPL",
    orderNo: "20180518-00001"
},
{
    repId: "22",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-00002"
},
{
    repId: "22 (2)",
    symbol: "FB",
    orderNo: "20180518-00002"
}]

const sortedArrayField = [
    "20180518-00001", 
    "20180518-00002", 
    "20180518-00003", 
    "20180518-00004"
];

var sortedArray = sortedArrayField.map(orderNo => unsortedArray.find(item => item.orderNo === orderNo));

console.log(sortedArray);

var sortedArray2 = [];
sortedArrayField.forEach(orderNo => {
  sortedArray2 = sortedArray2.concat(unsortedArray.filter(item => item.orderNo === orderNo));
});

console.log(sortedArray2);
```